# How to prevent BeautifulSoup from encoding escaping characters

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

As it's mentioned in the question - I want BeautifulSoup to keep original characters in HTML, instead of replacing them. Simple example:

```py
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(
    "APOLLOE4: Early Alzheimer&#39;s disease study",
    "html.parser",
)
html1 = str(soup1)
print(html1)
```

Current output:

```
"APOLLOE4: Early Alzheimer's disease study"
```

Expected output:

```
"APOLLOE4: Early Alzheimer&#39;s disease study"
```

I've found the BeautifulSoup docs topic where output formatters are explained (https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=escape#output-formatters), but I can't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation, when using BeautifulSoup to parse, the document (or the string) is first converted to Unicode, and HTML entities are **always** converted to Unicode characters for BS4 (the argument `convertEntities` which works in BeautifulSoup 3 doesn't work anymore.).

Therefore, after making the soup with `soup1 = BeautifulSoup("APOLLOE4: Early Alzheimer&#39;s disease study","html.parser")`, `&#39` has been converted.
And the encoding is unable to prevent.

I think a possible solution is to convert it back after the soup making like:

```
html1 = str(soup1).replace("'", "&#39;")
```